# Rg. OnWebKitInitialized not being invoked

Tags: javascript, c++

Respected Javascript users,

I am using CEF to bind JS with C++.I am running into the issue that OnWebKitInitialized is not being invoked at all. The native code binding is solely depending on this callback (correct me if I am wrong. But the only way the JS can call C++ is via this OnWebKitInitialized and Execute methods).

Here is the pseudo code for the initialization process:

```
 void OnInit(){
   HINSTANCE instance = wxGetInstance();
    CefMainArgs main_args(instance);

    CefRefPtr<CefApp> app = new MainHandler();
   int exit_code = CefExecuteProcess(main_args, app, nullptr);
   if (exit_code >= 0) {
    // The sub-process has completed so return here.
    return false;
   }

   // Specify CEF global settings here.
   CefSettings settings;
   settings.no_sandbox = true;
   settings.multi_threaded_message_loop = true;


   settings.ignore_certificate_errors = true;

   // Initialize CEF.
   CefInitialize(main_args, settings, app, nullptr);
```

}

Then in MainHandle class :

```
class MainHandle :  public CefApp, public CefBrowserProcessHandler, public CefRenderProcessHandler
{

  virtual OnContextCreated //full syntax
  virtual void OnContextInitialized() override;
  virtual void OnWebKitInitialized();
  void OnRenderProcessThreadCreated(CefRefPtr<CefListValue> extra_info) ;

  ..other related code
}
```

Here OnContextInitialized and OnRenderProcessThreadCreated are  being called, because the MainHandle is a subclass of browser process handler. But none of render process handler callbacks are being called.

Any one know how to make the OnWebKitInitialized get invoked? or if something might be wrong with the code above that might hinder the callback calling?

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution.

http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=12909

Quoting the member answer :

> OnWebKitInitialized and other CefRenderProcessHandler methods are called in the renderer process. You need to implement "CefApp::GetRenderProcessHandler()" and pass the CefApp instance to CefExecuteProcess().